Is there any such thing written somewhere else also - that When Krishna favours someone, he first makes him poor?
There is a verse in Shrimad Bhagwad Mahapurana that when Shri Krishna favours someone, he makes them poor.
Is there any such thing written somewhere else also. I have heard that such thing is written in Mahabharat also.
ŚB 10.88.8

श्रीभगवानुवाच
यस्याहमनुगृह्णामि हरिष्ये तद्धनं शनै: ।
ततोऽधनं त्यजन्त्यस्य स्वजना दु:खदु:खितम्


The Personality of Godhead said: If I especially favor someone, I gradually deprive him of his wealth. Then the relatives and friends of such a poverty-stricken man abandon him. In this way he suffers one distress after another.

ŚB 10.88.9

स यदा वितथोद्योगो निर्विण्ण: स्याद् धनेहया ।
मत्परै: कृतमैत्रस्य करिष्ये मदनुग्रहम्


When he becomes frustrated in his attempts to make money and instead befriends My devotees, I bestow My special mercy upon him

ŚB 10.88.10

तद् ब्रह्म परमं सूक्ष्मं चिन्मात्रं सदनन्तकम् ।
विज्ञायात्मतया धीर: संसारात्परिमुच्यते


A person who has thus become sober fully realizes the Absolute as the highest truth, the most subtle and perfect manifestation of spirit, the transcendental existence without end. In this way realizing that the Supreme Truth is the foundation of his own existence, he is freed from the cycle of material life.

